# Lots of ftpdxxx users on last command

Tags: login, last

When I execute "last" command to see users that have logged on my system, I have many connections like these:

```
ftp      ftpd28575    66.249.66.179    Thu Aug 11 20:41 - 20:42  (00:00)
ftp      ftpd26862    66.249.66.176    Thu Aug 11 20:33 - 20:33  (00:00)
ftp      ftpd26184    66.249.66.173    Thu Aug 11 20:29 - 20:29  (00:00)
ftp      ftpd22605    66.249.66.173    Thu Aug 11 20:10 - 20:10  (00:00)
ftp      ftpd6562     187.14.64.68     Thu Aug 11 18:47 - 18:48  (00:00)
```

In my /etc/passwd:

```
proftpd:x:122:65534::/var/run/proftpd:/bin/false
ftp:x:123:65534::/srv/ftp:/bin/false
```

What are these connections ?

Comment: Does your proftpd server have some sort of virtual user setup and/or users coming from some other source (SQL database, LDAP, etc.)?

Comment: No, but I noticed that every single access to my FTP is logging access to the shell (as seeing in "last" command). Nobody is accessing through SFTP, only via Browser.